Steinitz vs Mainline classical French
After

e4 e6

d4 d5

Nc3 Nf6


White has 2 main options, go for the Steinitz with 4) e5 or stick to the mainline or the Burn variation of the Classical French with Bg5. I want to know the differences between the kinds of positions that generally arise from the respective options and some resources (model games) to learn the more aggressive white response.
[Title "White's Two Main Options"]
[StartPly "6"]
[FEN ""]

1. e4 e6 2. d4 d5 3. Nc3 Nf6 4. e5 (4. Bg5)

